# jQuery adicionando varias linhas no html

Tags: jquery, html

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
 $("#divPrincipal").prepend('<p class="text-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' +     resultado + ' plantas </p>');
```

A idéia era clickar em um botão e ele imprimir a linha com o resultado no meu formulario HTML,entretanto se o usúario ficar clicando no botão ele ficará replicando está linha.Existe alguma modo de sobrescrever a linha, ou escrever a linha uma vez,ou imprimir o resultado de outra maneira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de complementar o conteúdo do div com `prepend` (ou `append`), defina o conteúdo todo com `.html()`:

```
$("#divPrincipal").html('<p class="text-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas </p>');
```

Isso limpa o div e preenche de novo com o conteúdo passado.

Comment: Nossa como sou burro rs,vlw ae

Comment: Às vezes a solução é mais simples do que a gente pensa ;)

Answer (score 2):

Só para complementar a resposta do @bfavaretto, se em alguma situação tiver que colocar um resultado num lugar já pré-determinado, pode usar o `.text` para mudar somente o conteúdo de um elemento:

```js
var resultado = 17;
$("#resultado").text( 'Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="text-success" id="resultado"></p>
```

Neste exemplo, o `<p>` já existe no HTML, e você está mudando apenas o conteúdo.

Nota: diferentemente do `.html`, se você usar um `.text( 'um <em>dois</em> tres' )`, o `<em>` vai aparecer escrito literalmente, em vez de enfatizar o `dois`.